# Two lists, if a common match is found print another list element

Tags: python, bash, compare, match

I have two text files, in the format.

```
File 1  
Column A    Column B      

File 2  
Column B    Column C
```

In File 2, Column B is only a subset of the data in File 1.

I wish to search File 1, if a match is found to Column B data point in File 2, print the Column A value.

Can anyone advise how to do this in an easy manner? Preferably either Python or Bash.

Thanks so much.

An example

```
File 1  
Bruce Dog  
Frank Cat  
Adam Fish  
Alex Horse  

File 2  
Dog Blue  
Fish Green
```

Would print:

```
Bruce  
Adam
```

Comment: Hello! What have you tried so far in Python or Bash? Which tutorials have you started and could not get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can easily be achieved by using dictionary

1. Create a Dictionary of the elements from the second file. Split each line as a key: value pair.
2. For Each line in your First File, split it again as Key: value and search the value in your dictionary
3. If Found, Print the value from your first file you are iterating

**Sample Implementation**

```
from itertools import imap
file2 = dict(imap(str.split, open("file2")))
with open("file1") as fin:
    for key, value in imap(str.split, fin):
        if value in file2:
            print key
```

**Note to OP**

If you are concerned with resource leak because of file handle not being closed explicitly, enclose the first statement in a with clause

```
with open("file2") as fin:
    file2 = dict(imap(str.split, fin))
```

Comment: This way, `file2` is never closed properly.

Comment: @tobias_k: There is a long standing debate on this, whether GC would close the file properly, and when it would be closed. I found no issues with this implementation. In case if you feel it has problem, feel free to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Here's a  thought of the algorithm:

1. Retrieve the lines in file A store them into variable `foo`
2. Retrieve the lines in file B store them into variable `bar`
3. Split the variable `foo` using white space into `foosplited`
4. Split the variable `bar` using white space into `barsplited`
5. Do a loop: for each element indexed of an odd number `i` in the `foosplited`, look through the elements indexed of an even number in `barsplited` if they're the same. If same, goto 6; not, goto 7
6. Print `foosplited[i-1]`
7. continue the loop
8. Halt

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {}

for line in file1:
    # The 2nd word will be the key, the 1st will be the value
    words = line.split()
    dict1(words[1]) = words[0]

for line in file2:
    words = line.split()
    if dict1.has_key(words[0]):
        print words[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ join -12 -21 -o 1.1 <(sort -k2,2 file1) <(sort file2)
Bruce
Adam
```

Because `join` requires the files to be sorted on the join field, the order of your output is not guaranteed. If you want the output in the same order as the input files, use `awk` -- plenty of examples here on SO if you search.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1:
    d = {v:k for (k,v) in [line.split() for line in f1]}
    with open('file2.txt') as f2:
        print [d[k] for (k,v) in [line.split() for line in f2]]

>>> ['Bruce', 'Adam']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file1","rt") as f1, open("file2","rt") as f2:
    data = {}
    for line in f1:
        line = line.replace("\n","")
        colA,colB = line.split(" ")[:2]
        data[colB] = colA
    for line in f2:
        colB = line.replace("\n","").split(" ")[0]
        out = data.get(colB)
        if out:
            print out
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary from the first file like:

```
dict1 = {
    "Dog": "Bruce Dog",
    "Cat": "Frank Cat"
}
```

So second column will be the keys and values will contain both. Then Make e `set` from the first column of the second file.

set1 = set(["Fish", "Dog"])

Then create another set from the `dict1` keys and take `intersection`

```
intersect = set(dict1.keys().intersection())
print intersect
>> set(["Dog"])
for i in intersect:
    print dict1[i]
```